# Log the time taken in each task when running a msbuild build

Tags: msbuild

We have a long-running msbuild script that I'm trying to speed up. Is there a way to get msbuild to log the time spent in each target?

I've had a look at the xml logger, but it just outputs the total time.

Would I have to make my own logger, or is there something built in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its actually quite easy, in the command line, just add this:

```
/consoleloggerparameters:PerformanceSummary
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also useful msbuild argument when you want to analyze which particular **project** in the solution is taken long time:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

> **/detailedsummary**  /ds Show detailed information at the end of the build
>   log about the configurations that were built and how they were
>   scheduled to nodes.

Fantastic explanation about format is given here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/03/05/msbuild-4-detailed-build-summary/