Visual Studio C# build time insights
At the company I work at, we have some builds that take a long time. The build time has gradually increased over the years.
Is there any way to have insight in what makes the build take long?
I've seen the "build insights" feature, but that only supports C++. We use C#.

Do you mean building locally in your VS or in a Pipeline on some Build-Server? If locally: there should be a build log running when you press "Build". Maybe you need to configure your VS to display it, though.

Yes, locally. There's logging in the output view. Can it display timestamps? It's also slow in the pipeline in azure devops, but that's less of an issue.

Yes. Try msbuild -consoleLoggerParameters:ShowTimestamp.

Not aware of if you can make it display timestamps. I would usually look at the "comprehesion" data at the end of the run for each project ...

Also see answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630894/log-the-time-taken-in-each-task-when-running-a-msbuild-build

^^ That makes it possible to be finer grained, of course.

We've found the issue after enabling timestamps in the Output view!
We had dotnet format set up at pre-build, which increased build time from 50 seconds to almost 5 minutes.

@Janneman96 I work on VS, particularly around build performance. Could you share more details about how you had this configured? If a pre-build event, could you share the XML from your project file that did this (an edit in your answer would be great). Thanks!

@DrewNoakes I removed something from the Directory.Build.props file. I don't think it's part of the question, as I wanted insight in build times. Showing the timestamps was an answer. Here's the part I removed so it runned better:




@DrewNoakes Would be great if you could add some kind of feature like you have in the network tab of a browser! So you can see the timespan of different actions.

Thanks, seeing that it was a PreBuild target is helpful. And yes we'd like to add more visibility here. The trick is doing it in a way that doesn't hurt build performance due to the overhead of logging everything that goes on during a build.

Good day, I'm glad you've found a way to display the timestamp. If possible, please post an answer so that others who encounter similar issues can see the solution.

@ZhenningZhang I've added an answer. Thanks for reminding me.

There currently does not seem to be an advanced way to gain insights in why a build takes long.
Enabling the timestamps in the output window gave me enough insight to resolve the issue, which is enabled by clicking the icon on the right in the output window:

